# How do you replace/remove rows during a dataTable update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

So, I am working on code that uses the [DataTables API](https://datatables.net/manual/api). It appears that it is using an older version of it though. So, my table updates every 5 seconds and all I need is for it to completely update when new new data comes in. However, while it input new update, data that is no longer referenced in that table stay there even though it should disappear, and my table just gets bigger and bigger over time. I've tried to use:

```
Table.fnClearTable(); // throws error below
TypeError: Cannot set property '_aData' of undefined
```

And this doesn't work. It removes everything, but won't let me rebuild a new table. I've also tried to use:

```
Table.fnDestroy(); // doesn't seem to work either
"bDestroy":true // didn't seem to work, but I couldn't tell
```

So, this is the particular function that I am working on. I'd like to to periodically either delete and recreate the table, or to do a better job at refreshing the data going into it.

```
my.updating.graph = function(obj, listAll) {
    try {
    if (obj == null || obj.updates == null || obj.updates.length == 0) {
        $("#sectionUpdates").hide();
        return;
    }
    $("#sectionUpdates").show();
    var table = null;
    if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable("updateTable")) { // may remove this statement...
        table = $("#updateTable").dataTable();
    } else {
        table = $("#updateTable").dataTable({ // is there a reset option?
            "paging": !listAll,
            "pagingType": !listAll ? "X" : "Y",
            "searching": true,
            "order": [
                [0, "desc"]
            ],
            "ordering": true,
            "oLanguage": {
                "sEmptyTable": "No updates at this time"
            },
            "iDisplayLength": 15,
            "info": false,
            "formatNumber": function(format) {
                return friendlyFormat(format, 1000, 0);
            },
            "aoColumns": [{
                    "bVisible": false
                },
                {
                    "className": "dt-center",
                    "width": "10%",
                    "iDataSort": 0,
                    "render": function(data, type, row) {
                        return extractData(data, type, row[0]);
                    }
                }, {
                    "sType": "mixed-string",
                    "className": "dt-left",
                    "width": "30%",
                    "render": function(data, type, row) {
                        return getZData(data, type, row[1]);
                    }
                }, {
                    "className": "dt-left",
                    "width": "30%",
                    "render": function(data, type, row) {
                        return getYData(data, type, row[2]);
                    }
                }, {
                    "sType": "mixed-string",
                    "className": "dt-left",
                    "width": "30%",
                    "render": function(data, type, row) {
                        return getZData(data, type, row[3]);
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        $("#updateTable").resize(function() {});
    }
    var updates = obj.updates;
    for (var i = 0; i < updates.length; i++) {
        var update = updates[i];
        var id = makeId(update.id);
        var triggered = getCurrentUTC();
        if (update) {
            if (getID("updateTable", id) == null) {
                var row = table.fnAddData([
                    update.field1,
                    update.field2,
                    update.field3,
                    update.field4
                ]);
                var node = $("#updateTable").dataTable().fnSettings().aoData[row[0]].nTr;
                node.setAttribute("id", "updateTable-item-" + id);
                node.setAttribute("rowIdx", row[0]);
                setID("updateTable", id, row[0]);
            }
            table.fnUpdate([
                    update.field1,
                    update.field2,
                    update.field3,
                    update.field4
                ], getID("updateTable", id),
                null, false, false);
            for (var q = 0; q < tblStatusClasses.length; q++) {
                $("updateTable-item-" + id + " td:eq(0)").removeClass(tblStatusClasses[q]);
            }
            $("#updateTable-item-" + id + " td:eq(0)").addClass("table-state" + update.field1);
        }
        table.fnStandingRedraw();
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you not upgrading to 1.10?  Then it is easy as $("#updateTable").DataTable().clear()

Comment: How difficult would it be to upgrade a pre-existing project over 10000+ lines (maybe 100000) long that uses the 1.9 version?

Comment: How much of that code is unique to datatables?

Comment: According to Alien, he tried to keep it backwards compatible.  I would just try changing the includes and see if there are side effects. http://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10